# Search a number from mother files in daughter file and append the complete line from daughter file back in mother file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file File1.txt with data in the following form

```
*ELEMENT_SHELL
$#   eid     pid      n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6         
 46573       1   48206   48210   48217   48205       0       0           
 46574       1   48205   48217   48218   48204       0       0
............................................................
.............................................................
```

I want to search for the number in the third column like 48206 and search it from the other file File2.txt  which has a format like under

```
text
text
48205       54.995392  -1.847287e-009      149.449997       0       0
48206       55.995308  -1.879442e-009      149.449997       0       0
48207       56.995224  -1.911598e-009      149.449997       0       0
text
48208       56.995224  -1.911598e-009      149.449997       0       0
...
```

and put the complete line along with the number back in the first file and append it at the end.
  so that File1.text will look like

```
*ELEMENT_SHELL
$#   eid     pid      n1      n2      n3      n4      n5      n6      
46573       1   48206   48210   48217   48205       0       0       
46574       1   48205   48217   48218   48204       0       0       
....................................................
............................................................
48206       55.995308  -1.879442e-009      149.449997       0       0
```

Any suggestion with SED or AWK?

Comment: You've tagged this with [processing], but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Processing language.

Comment: Actually with that it is meant to be word processing but the limit of words was a hurdle. In that sense should I remove that tag?

Comment: Well, the only people who look at the [processing] tag are people trying to answer questions about the Processing language, so I doubt it'll help you find any answers!

Comment: I removed it.. thanks for the comment.

Comment: `awk '/48206/||FNR==NR' file file2` ? or if you wanted it to get everything that matched from the third column `awk 'x=FNR==NR;NR>2&&x{a[$3]};($1 in a)' file file2`

Comment: @JID it is about everything, this is just a sample. my file have thousand of lines actually.

Comment: Second one does everything

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { print; if(NR > 2) { seen[$3] = 1 }; next } seen[$1]' file1 file2
```

The code works as follows:

```
NR == FNR {       # while processing the first file
  print           # print the line (echoing file1 fully)
  if(NR > 2) {    # from the second line onward
    seen[$3] = 1  # remember the third fields you saw
  }
  next            # don't do anything else.
}
seen[$1]          # while processing the second file: select lines
                  # whose first field is one of the remembered fields.
```

You can then redirect the output of this to another file and replace file1 with that file afterwards:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { print; if(NR > 2) { seen[$3] = 1 }; next } seen[$1]' file1 file2 > file1.new && mv file1.new file1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the field from file1 with `awk`, then find the matching lines in file2 with `grep` and simply concatenate the files afterwards.

```
while read LINE
do
    SEARCHSTR=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $3}')  
    grep "$SEARCHSTR" file2.txt >>append.txt
done < file1.txt

cat file1.txt append.txt >file1_append.txt
```

To have `grep` search for the content of different fields, a regex has to be constructed to contain them all, i.e.

```
SEARCHSTR=$(echo $LINE | awk '{BEGIN {OFS="|";} print $3, $4, $5}')  
grep "($SEARCHSTR)" file2.txt >>append.txt
```

Here `$SEARCHSTR` would already contain the content of the fields seperated by `|`.

Concerning speed: if the files have their columns at fixed positions, you could use `cut` instead of `awk` like this:

```
SEARCHSTR=$(echo $LINE | cut --output-delimiter="|" -c 15-20,21-26,27-32|tr -d " ")
```

Comment: it worked a little bit slow but its acceptable. I have to search actually $3, $4, $5 and $6 too and there are some numbers from each of them which get repeated in other, can you please suggest an edit to copy only once from each of 4 field? that would be magnficient. Otherwise, I would need to search the first field and get it deleted if it repeats. thanks

Comment: And for a speedier alternative, if your files have fixed record length.

Comment: is it possible to avoid redunduncy? like 48205 is once at $6 and once at $3 so it would be printed twice, can you suggest a fix to this problem? since the files are quite huge and it just takes alot of extra time.

Comment: I don't understand: the regex which contains the alternatives might contain the same string multiple times, but there will be only one match. Or are you talking about a value being repeated on multiple *lines*?